# Docker run python script cant find locally installed module

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-batch

For context, this problem relates to a docker image that will be run using azure batch.

Here is the `Dockerfile`, in full:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ADD . /pipegen

ADD environment.yml /tmp/environment.yml
RUN conda env create -f /tmp/environment.yml

RUN echo "conda activate $(head -1 /tmp/environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)" >> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/$(head -1 /tmp/environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)/bin:$PATH
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV $(head -1 /tmp/environment.yml | cut -d' ' -f2)

ADD classify.py /classify.py
RUN rm -rf /pipegen
```

`pipgen` is the local module (where the `Dockerfile` is located) that is installed using the `environment.yml` file. Here is the `environment.yml` file in full:

```
name: pointcloudz

channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - python-pdal
  - entwine
  - matplotlib
  - geopandas
  - notebook
  - azure-storage-blob==1.4.0
  - pip:
    - /pipegen
    - azure-batch==6.0.0
```

For clarity, the directory structure looks like this:

```
Dockerfile
pipegen
  \__ __init__.py
  \__ pipegen.py
  \__ utils.py
classify.py
batch_containers.py
environment.yml
setup.py
```

The `Dockerfile` establishes the environment created using the `environment.yml` file as the default (conda) python environment when the container is run. Therefore, I can run the container interactively as follows:

`docker run -it pdalcontainers.azurecr.io/pdalcontainers/pdal-pipelines`

and, from inside the container, execute the `classify.py` script with some command line arguments, as follows:

`python classify.py in.las out.las --defaults`

and the script is executed as expected. However, when I  run the following command, attempting to execute the very same script from "outside" the container,

`docker run -it pdalcontainers.azurecr.io/pdalcontainers/pdal-pipelines python classify.py in.las out.las --defualts`

I get the following error:

```
File "classify.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pipegen.pipegen import build_pipeline, write_las
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipegen'
```

Just to be clear, the `classify.py` script imports `pipegen`, the local module which is now installed in the conda environment created in the `Dockerfile`. I need to be able to execute the script using the `docker run` command above due to constraints in how Azure batch runs jobs. I've tried multiple fixes but am now pretty stuck. Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the constraints placed by Azure Batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you added the `conda activate` to the `.bashrc` script which is only activated for login shells.  When you run the container interactively, that is what you are getting.  However, when you just try to invoke the python script directly, you do not get a login shell so your conda environment is **not** activated.

One think you could do is not use the conda activate and instead run the script with `conda run`.  To simplify the command-line, add this entrypoint to your Dockerfile:

`ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV", "python", "classify.py"]`

Using this in the entrypoint also allows the caller to pass command-line arguments via docker run.

From the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

> Command line arguments to docker run  will be appended after all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT

For a more detailed explanation, see [Activating a Conda environment in your Dockerfile](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/)

Comment: Thanks veru much Nick that's super helpful and clarifying. That sounds like the perfect solution if I was running the same script each time which didn't require command line arguments to be passed to it. I'm stuck trying to figure out a solution which would allow for new arguments to be passed for each "job" in azure batch. Any ideas there?

Comment: @JmeCS, You can pass command-line arguments when using entrypoint.  I updated the answer to include the relevant reference for this.